# JScript user asks how to build a a home made JavaScript interpreter to avoid limitations

Tags: javascript

I know how to do my jobs by C++. I like to move most of 
them to Windows Script Host JScript. But Windows JScript 
doesn't do many important things.

Many JavaScript kernels are open source, and we have node.js,
processing.js already.

So we need to be able to build our own JavaScript interpreter
so as to bypass JScript. This sounds true for desktop applications
, right?

I need some hints to start it. It's worthy even if it takes years.

JScript limitations are : 
1. can't access hardware.
2. can't do things that need administrator privilege.

A JScript wrapper like xNeat http://www.xneat.com helps JScript to call APIs. But it does not work with WinIO (access I/O ports and physical memory) because WinIO needs administrator privilege that is not allowed by JScript.

I'll try to compile V8 or the likes and remove restrictions it intentionally made for security then add some low level interfaces to call Windows APIs, which JScript can't do. I think this is cool. Maybe I don't even need to do that again because somebody already done that?

Comment: What are you hoping to gain? What limitations are you talking about? And why can't you just use an interpreter like v8?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about v8. Sounds like v8 is a JavaScript host running on Windows DOS box command line? This is that hint I want anyway. Thank you again!

Comment: It's the JS engine behind Chrome and Node.js. Also, I'd recommend using Lua instead of Javascript, since it's a simpler language and much easier to embed in C++. It's also quite fast.

Comment: I like to try Lua. Thanks. But JavaScript is everywhere. I'll try to compile V8 or the likes and remove restrictions it intentionally made for security then add some low level interfaces. I think this is cool.

Comment: Lua is also everywhere: WoW, Wikipedia, Adobe, [etc](https://sites.google.com/site/marbux/home/where-lua-is-used).

Answer (score 2):

You seriously need a lot more research... I'll try & save a few flops of Google:

- JScript != JavaScript. Assuming you are using them interchangably
  without knowing about the existence of proprietary [JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) from
  Microsoft..
- Javascript was never meant to do things you mention as limitations. It's supposed to run in web browsers & obviously a random website whose JS it is, should not be able to access/execute anything in the user's machine.
- Although contrary to belief that JS does not need to touch the file system, the [filesystem API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/) was brought in. I feel, that expands the  boundaries wide enough for any web application to leverage on.
- Besides, you can always [develop desktop apps for windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/jj680875) in JS, by the libraries exposed by Microsoft, but that's another story.

Comment: Thank you very much for the 'another story' hyperlink. I guess it could be what I need.

Comment: glad that it helped. You should have simply worded the question as "How to develop windows app in JS"

Comment: Nope, being able to write a JavaScript interpreter is still very cool. Node.js and processing.js already done that. The question is too big sorry about that.